# How to configure pylint for PyCharm using pyproject.toml?

Tags: pycharm, pylint, pyproject.toml

In the pylint settings of PyCharm 2022.1.2 I have

[image]

And I get the error (with a previous version of PyCharm it worked):

```
The scan failed due to an exception: pylintrc file is not valid. File does not exist or can't be read.
```

Unfortunately, there is no extra path setting for pyproject.toml files.

=> How can I tell PyCharm to **read the pylint configuration from** **pyproject.toml** without getting an error message?

Comment: Well, from the looks of it, you can't. You should check if there is a feature request for it already on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY, and create one yourself if there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Facepalm*

Actually, I just used a wrong path. Following relative path worked when specified as "Path to pylintrc":

```
./back_end/pyproject.toml
```

It's also possible to specify it in the **Arguments** field using the **--rcfile** option:

```
--rcfile C:\python_env\workspace\my_project\back_end\pyproject.toml
```

A **relative path** also works (relative to the project directory):

```
--rcfile ./back_end/pyproject.toml
```

PyCharm **path variables** like $PROJECT_DIR$ **do not seem to be supported**:

```
--rcfile $PROJECT_DIR$/back_end/pyproject.toml
```

does not work.